# Is there a service to help transcribe Kurrentschrift into Latin script?

Tags: resource, online-resource, handwriting, kurrent

I have several documents that I need transcribed from Kurrentschrift into modern German script (really just a text file, notepad would be perfect). Some examples of the documents I'm looking to have transcribed are below.

I'm not necessarily looking for a free service, though that would be nice. I'm just looking for an accurate transcription. I've got 50 or so documents that I need transcribed but not sure where to turn to.

[image: example document 1]
[image: example document 2]
[image: example document 3]

Comment: I don't know of any professional service, but I personally know an older person with very good knowledge of Kurrentschrift who has done this before, and who would probably like to do it for a small consideration.

Comment: Homes for the elderly sometimes organize events where residents (who can read Kurrent from their youth) help folks to read old documents. This, of course, is only an option if you live somewhere in a German-speaking country or at a place that many Germans emigrated to.

Comment: Sorry for being pedantic about the title of your question, but, AFAIK, Kurrent __is__ a Latin script.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are several options:

- Ask an American professional genealogist with a German genealogy focus ([search the directory](https://www.apgen.org/directory/search.html) of the Association of Professional Genealogists (APG) for *German American* specialists) or a German professional genealogist ([list](http://www.berufsgenealogie.net/german/mitglieder-1.html)).
- Ask a non primarily genealogy related service like [Altdeutsche Schreibstube](http://www.altdeutsche-schreibstube.de/), [Alphatrad](http://www.alphatrad.at/aktuelles/transkribieren-altdeutsch-suetterlin), [Czau](http://czau.net/de/kurrentschrift/) or [Recherche-Dienste](http://recherche-dienste.de/transkription/) for their estimates of cost. A Google search [for *kurrent transkription*](https://www.google.de/search?q=kurrent%20transkribtion) will show much more services.
- Ask a voluntary service like those operating often from old people's homes (see [a list at Sütterlinstube](http://www.suetterlinstube.org)). You could send them prints or they might even accept digital files. This is as far as I know free of charge, but a donation is appropriate.
- Upload your documents - one document a time - to the *Lesehilfe* (reading help) section of a forum like [Ahnenforschung.net](http://forum.ahnenforschung.net) or [Genealogy.net](http://forum.genealogy.net/index.php?page=Board&boardID=62) (free of charge).

*Disclaimer: I am not affiliated with any of the commercial services.*